# I tried installing Ubuntu 10.04 and I got this message - any ideas on what to do?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, partitioning, root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I tried installing Ubuntu 10.04 and I got this message - any ideas on what to do?](https://superuser.com/questions/222503/i-tried-installing-ubuntu-10-04-and-i-got-this-message-any-ideas-on-what-to-do)

*No root file system defined. Please correct this from the partition menu.*

This message shows up when I first boot into Ubuntu after the installation.

I installed it by mounting the ISO with Daemon Tools, and I just did the default Wubi installation. I keep reading everywhere that I need to choose my installation directory, but I don't get any option to do that. These are all the options I get for installation directory:

[image]

I have a C and D partition on my drive, and I tried installing it on both and no luck either way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I know that is not an answer to your question, and maybe you've already walked along this path but...why don't you try Lucid Lynx within VirtualBox or VMWare?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there a bug which messes with multiple boot systems.

[phoronix.com/](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ODE5Ng)

From [lifehacker- the-best-improvements-in-ubuntu-1004-lucid-lynx](http://lifehacker.com/5527259/the-best-improvements-in-ubuntu-1004-lucid-lynx?skyline=true&s=i):

> boot options for non-Ubuntu partitions can stop working. The fix is to run sudo update-grub from a terminal, or after hitting Alt+F2 for a prompt, and Ubuntu is working on "re-spinning" the ISO images that are affected.

Answer (score 0):

The Wubi installer might have installed Ubuntu as a program *within* Windows instead. If that isn't what you intended, then you might need to "uninstall" Ubuntu from Add/Remove Programs, and follow the steps provided in [this Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony).

Disclaimer: I'm an Ubuntu/Linux newbie. I'm also waiting for more experienced users to pitch in with their ideas as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with wubi, but definitely sounds like a bug here. The problem here is of linux is unable to find and mount the filesystem! As per the wubi documentation, it should mount c:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk (or D or whatever drive you opt for) as the root filesystem. 
But in your case this is failing.

Maybe you could check if the file exists? More then that I can't help you.

If I may, I would suggest to install Ubuntu on a separate partition instead of going through wubi. Wubi will generally will be slow.